# Java Generic Class Instantiation without Type Argument

Tags: java, generics

In the code below, if I instantiate Generic as:

```
Generic gen=new Generic(1,2);
```

that is without type argument,then when i do this:

```
int a=gen.get_a();
```

it does not work and gives

> required:int     Found:Java.Lang.Object

but `ob.print()` works.
So when I do this instead:

```
int a=(Integer)gen.get_a();
```

then it works. So does the erasure replace `T` with `Object` type since `T` cannot be primitive, when no type argument is passed?

```
public class Generic<T>
{
    T a;
    Generic(T a)
    {
        this.a=a;
    }
    void print()
    {
        System.out.print(a);
    }

    T get_a()
    {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically you're using a raw type. See http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html#Raw Types

Comment: Thank You!! I got it now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, as Jon Skeet said, you are using a raw type in your variable declaration.

```
 Generic gen=new Generic(1,2);
 int a=gen.get_a();
```

> it does not work and gives

```
required:int Found:Java.Lang.Object
```

The compiler cannot guess the type if you don't specify it when you declare the variable.

> So does the erasure replace T with Object type since T cannot be
>   primitive, when no type argument is passed?

Using types demands specifying class in the declaration. And a primitive is not a class.
`Generic<int> gen = new Generic<>(1);` will not compile

So, you have to specify the wrapper object of int primitive if you want to type your instance with an integer value :
`Generic<Integer> gen = new Generic<>(1);`
You must have done noticed it when you declare a collection variable with generics relying on numeric types.

`Object` is the root class in Java and as in your case`T` doesn't extend any explicit class, `T` derives from `Object` implicitly.
So, it you use a raw type in your variable, you manipulate objects.
I suppose that the compiler considers that the returned type of unspecified `T` is the most specific and compatible type for `T` and in your case it is `Object`.
 You have the same behavior with a collection : at compile-time, a raw `java.util.List` manipulates `Object` when `T` is encountered.

---

**Edit** :
Here, I will give you another example to illustrate that with raw types, instead of declare type, the `Object` class is not necessarily used by the compiler if the type declared in the class extends another class. Contrary to what you may think.

If the `Generic` class was declared like that :

```
public class Generic<T extends MyClass>{
...
}
```

Even by using a raw type in the declaration of the variable, `get_a()` would return a `MyClass` object since the most specific and compatible type for `T` is not `Object` but `MyClass`.

```
 Generic gen = new Generic(1);
 MyClass myClass = gen.get_a(new MyClass());
```

Comment: Thank You. I got it now, in my code if i added <T extends Number> it says 
Found: Java.Lang.Number
as you showed in the example. Thank You!! :)

Another Question struck me, if I do say:

LinkedList<Integer> list=new LinkedList<>();
List<Number> l=list;

This does not work, I know, but suppose
List l_interface=list
This works, is l_interface also a raw type, means l_interface will also derive Object implicitly?? I

Comment: You are welcome :) `List l_interface ` declaration is a List of anything. So the compiler replaces the generic by the most general type : `Object`.
When you write `LinkedList<Integer> list = ...; List l_interface = list`, you assign a list object using generics  to a reference which is a raw list. The compiler doesn't prevent you from doing that but it warns you (with warning) and you lose the generic mechanism since this list is a list of object..

Comment: Thanks!!! :) Got it, understood a lot about generics and raw type through these today.

Comment: Is it possible ? <code> public constructor(Generic<> aGenTypeInstanceParam) </code>