# Java generic class method with a generic return type gives unchecked conversion warning

Tags: java, generics

**Edit:**
I found the second duplicate matched my question the best and was the most useful.

I have a generic class which has a method with a generic return type. The return type's concrete class is given in the definition. When I use the method, the compiler gives unchecked conversion warning.

An example will explain it better.

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> {
   public List<String> getStringList() {
      return new ArrayList<String>();
   }
}

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyGenericClass mgc = new MyGenericClass<>();
      List<String> myStringList = mgc.getStringList();
   }
}
```

The last line in the main method causes the compiler warning:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
            List<String> myStringList = mgc.getStringList();
                                                         ^
required: List<String>
found:    List
```

This problem does not occur when I specify T. For example when I use Integer as T, the problem does not occur.
It is not good to use a generic class without specifying a type but I couldn't understand why the return type 'List<String>' becomes 'List' when I don't specify T. Does anyone know the logic behind this, and can you point me to the related section of JLS?

Comment: `MyGenericClass<String> mgc `

Comment: Why do you have a generic here ? You don't use `T`

Comment: I would suggest checking this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41442431/4916630

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I mentioned that, this problem does not occur when I specify a type.

Comment: @AxelH This question is theoretical, I mentioned that we should not use Generics without specifying a type.

Comment: @AntonKrosnev That question is about a method with the return type T. Here, the method is not related with the generic type.

Comment: @meribald see the extra dupe I added. OldCurmudgeon provides the relevant JLS references there.