# Android - How to dynamically select an AsyncTask with different generic types at runtime?

Tags: android, generics, polymorphism

Let me start by saying I am an experienced Python developer who is feeling very lost in the Android/Java ecosystem. I am having trouble understanding what I expected should be a very simple use of polymorphism. The exact problem I'm trying to solve is that I have an activity that needs to select an implementation at runtime based on the incoming data.

For my first feature, handling a file, I discovered that I need to implement an AsyncTask to offload the actual work of reading the file and handling the content. No problem, I implemented the AsyncTask as follows:

`class UploadUriTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Integer, String>`

I added a member variable of type `UploadUriTask` to my activity class and everything worked great:

`private UploadUriTask task;`

However, the second feature I want to add is to handle URLs instead of files. While my first AsyncTask implementation took its `Params` as `Uri[]`, this new task needs to take them as `String[]`:

`class UploadUrlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>`

At this point I'm thinking that both of these classes extend `AsyncTask` so I can just change my member variable to an `AsyncTask`:

`private AsyncTask task;`

On activity create, I check the incoming data type and instantiate the appropriate task:

```
if (dataType.equals("image/*")) {
  task = new UploadUriTask(this);
}
else {
  task = new UploadUrlTask(this);
}
```

However, now when either of my tasks gets called, the `Params` types are being converted to `Object[]` instead of `Uri[]` or `String[]` as evidenced by the error I get when calling `task.execute(url)`:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]`

I feel like I'm just missing something super obvious here, but I can't seem to figure out the right terms to search for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `private AsyncTask task;` Your variable is stored as a raw type, so any type parameters are erased. `AsyncTask` type parameters are unbounded so they default to `Object` (java class root) when the type parameters are erased like that.
This is why `execute` then expects params of type `Object[]`

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442057/java-generic-class-instantiation-without-type-argument) in more detail

> The compiler cannot guess the type if you don't specify it when you
>   declare the variable.

As per the exception, `Object[]` cannot be cast to `String[]` as `String[]` is not a subclass of `Object[]`

Comment: OK conceptually that makes sense, but I can't specify it at declaration because it needs to be dynamically selected at runtime. I would just declare it locally but it is needed in another class method override.